# VPN to Home server throught VPN

Tags: vpn, iptables, wireguard

I have a **Home server** behind a NAT provider, I want to connect to it via VPN from a **Remote laptop** (Windows) to use its region IP.

I have a **VPS server** with a **Wireguard server** configured, and a **client** configured on my Laptop and Home server.

How can I set up a tunnel from Wireguard client to Wireguard client?

### Network map

[image]

Comment: You cannot forward the necessary ports to run a VPN since you are behind a NAT provider

Comment: You should be able to connect the Home Server to an external VPN and then configure that VPN to allow clients to talk to each other with the VPN IP addresses. If both are Home Server and Remote Laptop are connected to the VPN, can they ping each others private VPN IP addresses? You are not asking about allowing VPN port traffic for a server behind the NAT provider but how to get those to talk once both are connected to the same VPN, right?

Comment: I think the OP ultimately wants to use the Home Server / Fiber Terminal as its Internet gateway. ("Region IP")

Comment: And the solution is, set up policy route on the wireguard server to "loopback" forward the traffics from the tunnel into the tunnel, with your Home Server connected as a client as well. You'll need to set `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` under the `[Peer]` section of the Home Server in the  *wireguard server* conf. Your Home Server will need to do NAT (or set up static "return" route for the wireguard subnet in the "parent" router, if any and possible, with the Home Server as gateway) and IP(v4) forwarding.